# c# object instantiation

Tags: c#, object

What's the difference between:

```
Object o = new Object();
o.foo();
```

and

```
new Object().foo();
```

(assuming I do not need the reference afterwards) ?

Are there any reasons for using one instead of the other one (e.g. memory usage) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference in terms of execution.

There *can* be a difference in terms of debugging:

- It can be handy to break after the object has been created but before `foo()` is called
- It can be handy to be able to inspect the value of the variable afterwards
- If an exception is thrown, separating calls into multiple lines can make the source clearer. (I don't think it would be a problem in this particular case, but for `NullReferenceException`s in particular, it can be tricky if there are multiple dereferencing operations in the same statement).

I'm definitely *not* saying that you should always split everything out - just that it *can* be useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: Another difference is that - once declared - you can't reuse the variable name o again in the same scope. Probably a moot point, but a difference nonetheless.

Comment: @Jono, think that by scope you really mean declaration space. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx

Comment: @Fede, I'm only parroting back the compiler error that would follow: A local variable named 'o' is already declared in this scope. And we start to drift off topic...

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference if you don't need the instance afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need `o` afterwords then there is no difference.
The (JIT) compiler will probably treat them as being the same.

So it's a matter of taste. In this case I have a slight preference for the first one, but sometimes the fluent notation of the second sample is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

No difference.

To probe it, you can compile both codes (release mode), inspect them with ildasm and you will see the resulting bytecode witll be the same.

EDIT: actually, I sometimes find it easier to debug when the variable is declared. Easier to inspect, so, easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Removed incorrect code

The difference is that in the first case you can see the object being created in the debugger.

Comment: @Daniel Rose: actually that won't compile as well, a cast should be made for a class that has the `foo` method, but thanks for the answer

Comment: @Daniel: Why would you need to do that? Those parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: @user1112111: I reused your code. Obviously Object() doesn't have a foo Method. @Jon Skeet: You are right. My bad.